# Каков синтаксис описаний (synopsis) команд?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

Например SYNOPSIS команды `apt`:

```
apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [ -t=target_release] [ -
a=architecture] {list | search | show | update | install
pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]... | remove  pkg... | upgrade 
| full-upgrade | edit-sources | {-v | --version} | {-h | --help}}
```

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.8.en.html

Что означают все эти скобки, палки и многоточия или курсив? Есть мнение что синтаксис вообще не документирован и написан чисто от балды.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Интересный вопрос. Что-то я ранее не задумывался, т.к. такое описание встречается повсеместно в документации как разных утилит, так и в документации к языкам программирования.

[Оказывается](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140637), этот синтаксис не только документирован, но и является частью `POSIX` стандарта, описанного в части [`Utility Argument Syntax`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)

Кратко по основным моментам:

```
utility_name [-a] [-b] [-c option_argument]
    [-d|-e] [-f[option_argument]] [operand...]
```

- сначала пишется название утилиты, за ней параметры и аргументы
- в квадратных скобках указываются необязательные опции и аргументы
- аргументы упомянутые в одной группе через разделитель `|` означают, что эти аргументы взаимно-исключающие и не могут использоваться совместно
- троеточие означает, что допустимо несколько этот параметр несколько раз
- упоминаний `{}` в стандарте не вижу, очевидно это сделано для облегчения чтения и записи описания утилиты с множеством взаимоисключающих параметров. По стандарту синопсис должен был быть записан как-то так:

  ```
  apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] list
  apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] search
  apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] show
  apt [-h] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] update
  # и так далее на каждое действие
  ```

Comment: Ещё в description к `man` есть про болд и курсив. Помимо фигурных скобок ещё пробелы вставляют как хотят. Бесит это тяпляпство.

Comment: @Hipster, а еще про синтаксис аргументов, как они представлены  внутри программ и как их парсить [хорошо написано здесь](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments)

Comment: @Hipster, ну так поправьте и пришлите патч(и) -- люди только рады будут.

Comment: @0andriy Я новичок, пусть профессионалы правят. В `crontab -e` тоже пробелы кое как расставили в строке `# m h  dom mon dow   command`. Прям бесит этот тяп-ляп.

Comment: Ну вот и поправьте в качестве изучения -- жаловаться каждый может.